# Random spawning within a set distance in a circle

Tags: java, random, sprite, geometry

So, what I am looking for is a way to spawn a sprite in a random place at 30 pixels away from the player's sprite. How would I do this?

Comment: Very effortless question.. At least show an attempt.

Comment: Pick a random angle, then use trigonometry.

Comment: Why is it that programmers think that high school maths doesn't apply to them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have already told you, you should at least have an attempt to the code, else you're abusing the purpose of the website.

Nevertheless:

```
radius = Math.random()*maxRadius;
angle = Math.random()*2*Math.PI;
x = Math.cos(angle)*radius + x_of_circle_center;
y = Math.sin(angle)*radius + y_of_circle_center;
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm still in High School. I've just never done trigonometry with circles yet. Thank you for helping me though!